# Using Chrome component as WebView app container

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I have issue: in standard browser on some Android 4.2-4.4 devices my html page in some reasons (which I don't understand yet) looks broken as like as part of css just lost. But in Chrome app they are always looks good. So is there option to use Chrome app as main container for my webview application?

Answer (score 1):

> So is there option to use Chrome app as main container for my webview application?

`WebView` is using Chromium on Android 4.4+.

You cannot embed Chrome in your app, other than to the extent that `WebView` does.

IIRC, there are third-party libraries for embedding alternative Web rendering engines in an app. I seem to recall there being a standalone Chromium build, and Mozilla was working on allowing Gecko to be used as a library. I have not checked on the status of these in quite some time. You would also then be responsible for security updates for those Web rendering engines, and the libraries may substantially increase the size of your app.